# Is it possible to reduce stress by directly reducing cholestrol intake?

Tags: nutrition, stress, cholesterol, cortisol

"Cortisol is a glucocorticoid hormone synthesized from cholesterol by enzymes..."

- [Dartmouth University](http://dujs.dartmouth.edu/2011/02/the-physiology-of-stress-cortisol-and-the-hypothalamic-pituitary-adrenal-axis/#.Wps9IYJG2jQ)

I also found some sites that mentioned that higher cholestrol resulted from people who were more stressed, but I believe there might be a confounding factor whereby people eat more unhealthy foods to compensate for stress.

Is it possible that reducing cholestrol would lead to a direct, causational decrease in cortisol production? I wonder, is there a precise biological mechanism whereby we can reduce stress by reducing cholestrol intake?

Comment: Sure, take a holiday in the sun.  Stress levels fall, and vitamin D is synthesized from cholesterol as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not possible "that reducing cholestrol would lead to a direct, causational decrease in cortisol production?"

There is a little and a bigger flaw in this thought. Cholesterol [is not "bad"](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/12368/is-eating-too-much-cholesterol-bad/13943#13943) and it is not an essential nutrient. That means, *reduced **intake*** of this substance results usually just in *increased **synthesis*** of that substance.

> Cholesterol (from the Ancient Greek chole- (bile) and stereos (solid), followed by the chemical suffix -ol for an alcohol) is an organic molecule. It is a sterol (or modified steroid), a type of lipid molecule, and **is biosynthesized by all animal cells, because it is an essential structural component of all animal cell membranes and is essential to maintain both membrane structural integrity and fluidity.** Cholesterol allows animal cells to function without a cell wall (which in other species protects membrane integrity and cell viability); this allows animal cells to change shape rapidly. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesterol))

Further, it is not true that high cholesterol > leads to/causes > high cortisol >  leads to/causes > high stress.  It is more the other way around. Reduce stress and you reduce cortisol production and bad levels/ratios of lipoproteins ("high cholesterol").

> The second major physiological stress, the HPA axis regulates the release of cortisol, which influences many bodily functions such as metabolic, psychological and immunological functions. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(biology)) to [compare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_stress) with.)

Completely blocking cholesterol intake *and* synthesis would be quite deadly.

Comment: 20-40% of total cholesterol can be manipulated by diet.